# How to unwrap spans with empty class-Names <span class="">assign </span>?

Tags: javascript, html, text, unwrap, preserve

Does anybody has an idea to remove the `<span class="">TEST</span>` with jquery or javascript?
The innerHTML hier "TEST" shall be preserved. Looks easy but i didn't find an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
$('span[class=""]').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});
```

But if you really wanna use unwrap you could use:

```
$('span[class=""]').each(function() {
    $(this.childNodes).unwrap();
});
```